# How do you return result after entering text in form in django?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning

As an exercise I'd like to write a web app that returns keyword prediction after user enters content in the form. So, if a user enters some "text" in form, then below the form in, the keyword should appear.

I'm thinking that one approach could be using redirect to another view function that produces the prediction model function in view then the returned result would be a revised template. But, I'm not too sure about the following:

1. Could multiple functions be placed in the view under the same url patterns?
2. Is there an if condition that can be applied on the same template holding the form such that if the user submits, then the template shows results?

**View:**

```
def content_to_predict(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('show_prediction_result')
    else:
        form = InputForm()
    return render(request, 'prediction/content_input.html', {'form': form})
```

**Template:**

```
<h1> Input Content: </h1>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So the user types some text, posts the form and some words appear? Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Use posts submitted gets sent to a classification algorithm which makes a keyword prediction that should appear below the form.

Comment: Essentially, it's just a glorified version of a simple hit and retrieval procedure I'm trying to build.